# Is it possible to fold text with LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: linux, libreoffice-writer

Is it possible to fold text with LibreOffice Writer?

I'm talking about a way to have not so much used lines folded into just one, that can be expanded if you click on the '+' that lies on the left. This exists in quite a lot of text editors.

If possible, I'd like it to be recursive, so that text can be folded within text that can be folded. This forms a tree, similar to what we find in many file explorers, or in regedit in windows, for example.

Comment: Libre office probably won't have this feature because it's designed to be MS word for free. If you want to write code, I suggest using Eclipse. It has plugins that will compile and syntax check most major languages, and it's free.

Comment: Libre Office Calc has collapsible rows. Data -> Groups and Outline -> Group. I don't know if you are willing to use Calc instead of Writer though.

Comment: @user157127 who says this is for editing code?!

Comment: Hello. 2017 here :D Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't exist, but [other people have expressed interest in seeing the same](http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/2596/text-folding-pretty-please/). I have found the LibreOffice development team to be extremely approachable, friendly, and helpful -- I'm not sure they'd drop everything and implement this for you, but I'm sure if you could get someone else's interest who is very enthusiastic about adding this, you could work together to pull it off.

Still, the reality is that you can't do this today. Sometimes the right answer is "no"...

Comment: okay, thanks, too bad. The fact is, I still need this done. What approach would give a similar result ? Maybe a table of contents ? How to do that ? I'm writing a text that is composed of various items divided into a tree architecture, and I would like the ability for the user to get back and forth easily between different items, without having to scroll up/down or search for specific items.

Comment: A combination of using heading styles and wiring up a keyboard shortcut to a macro to advance to the next heading/section should help... if you're serious about it, try ask.libreoffice.org or stackoverflow, those are programming sites... but the querant is expected to have *some* knowledge of the subject matter, so if you don't know VBA or at least one macro language to OpenOffice, learn a bit of it first :)

Comment: Relevant enhancement request: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47746